# rabbitmq cluster unable to connect to nodes

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed rabbitmq in two machines.And they all worked well.
Then I run the command:`rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@rabbit1`, it's not work.And the error info:

```
Error: unable to connect to nodes [rabbit@rabbit1]: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@rabbit1]

rabbit@rabbit1:
* connected to epmd (port 4369) on rabbit1
* epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
* TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

* Hostname mismatch: node "rabbit@localhost" believes its host is different. 
Please ensure that hostnames resolve the same way locally and on 
"rabbit@localhost"


current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-66@localhost'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: 9z8msPdTpEUf5GeMrHGIqQ==
```

I searched it in google, and I had modified my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 rabbit2  localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 
localhost4.localdomain4
::1 rabbit2        localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 
localhost6.localdomain6

11.168.1.232 rabbit1
11.168.1.172 rabbit2
```

And the .erlang.cookie I made them the same.

Comment: maybe the firewall ?

Comment: no, I solved this by restart my os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this problem by restart my os when I modified the /etc/hosts.And finally it worked, I guess it would be the /etc/hosts not taking effect.